# HTTP doesn't work, HTTPS does

Tags: macos

MacBook Pro with Mavericks after resume, HTTP doesn't work but HTTPS does. No firewall, no proxy. HTTP does work in virtualized machines (everyone, one Ubuntu, one Windows 7 and a Windows Server 2008)

You just try in terminal telnet whateverdomain.whatevertopleveldomain 80 ...just nothing.

I'm lost

Comment: Please re-ask this from your registered account. We can sort out merging them later...  Not being able to edit the original post is going to make this hard to work and get you a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try typing "curl -v http://domain.com" and see if you can fetch the page that way. Try a few different sites, to rule out one specific site being down.

Also, try confirming there's no proxy set by using:
networksetup -getwebproxy Wi-Fi  (if you're connected via wifi)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you switch WiFi off and then on again? I see this all the time. If you use a proxy server, have you tried using a FQDN for it?

Do you roam from access point to access point at the time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not behind any proxy. It doesn't matter what wi-fi or ethernet network I'm connected to. As I said before, my virtual machines (Virtual Box using "bridge adapter" mode or NAT, both modes work anyway)can perform HTTP operations with no trouble at all.

That's what happens with curl -v (website I can access using HTTPS)

- *MacBook-Pro-de-Daniel:Desktop Dani$ curl -v http://burbuja.info

  - Adding handle: conn: 0x7fe78c004000
  - Adding handle: send: 0
  - Adding handle: recv: 0
  - Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
  - - Conn 0 (0x7fe78c004000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  - About to connect() to burbuja.info port 80 (#0)
  - Trying 198.41.249.62...
  - Connected to burbuja.info (198.41.249.62) port 80 (#0)

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
>   Host: burbuja.info
>   Accept: */*
>
> Empty reply from server
>
> Connection #0 to host burbuja.info left intact
>
> curl: (52) Empty reply from server*

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Do not post a comment as an answer: edit your question and add the additional info instead.

Comment: @matteo. The accounts are messed up, perhaps starting over would be best if da grapple can't self merge the two accounts...